# CakePHP Authentication Plugin Identity Associations

Tags: authentication, cakephp, associations, cakephp-3.x

I'm using CakePHP 3.8 and migrating to the Authentication Plugin (https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/1.1/en/index.html).

When calling `$this->Authentication->getIdentity()->getOriginalData()` in a controller, I'd like to access a couple of assocations of my `User` entity.

At the moment, I'm doing this by implementing the following `IdentityInterface` method in my `User` entity:

```
public function getOriginalData() {
  $table = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get($this->getSource());
  $table->loadInto($this, ['Activities', 'Clients']);
  return $this;
}
```

But I feel there should be a `contain` parameter somewhere within the Plugin configuration (as there was with the `AuthComponent`).

Can anyone guide me on how to include assocations on the User entity when calling `getIdentity()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `contain` option of the authentication objects for the old Auth component has been deprecated quite some time ago, and the recommended method is to use a custom finder, and that's also how it's done in the new authentication plugin.

The ORM resolver takes a `finder` option, and it has to be configured via the used identifier, which in your case is probably the password identifier, ie something like:

```php
$service->loadIdentifier('Authentication.Password', [
    // ...
    'resolver' => [
        'className' => 'Authentication.Orm',
        'finder' => 'authenticatedUser' // <<< there it goes
    ],
]);
```

In the finder method in your table class (probably `UsersTable`) you can then contain whatever you need:

```
public function findAuthenticatedUser(\Cake\ORM\Query $query, array $options)
{
    return $query->contain(['Activities', 'Clients']);
}
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Controllers > Components > AuthComponent > Customizing The Find Query](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#customizing-find-query)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Custom Finder Methods](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#custom-finder-methods)**
- **[Authentication Cookbook > Identifiers](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/1.1/en/identifiers.html)**
- **[Authentication Cookbook > Identifiers > ORM Resolver](https://book.cakephp.org/authentication/1.1/en/identifiers.html#orm-resolver)**

Comment: That's great, thanks. It has to be a career low when you're doing deprecated of deprecated!